# Using variables from create in the update function Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

In my game I am trying to use one of my variables I have initiated in my create function outside of that scope and to be used in the update function. Ideally my code would look like this:

```js
create()
    {
       const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'mainmap' })
       const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('Serene_Village_16x16', 'tiles', 16, 16, 1, 2)

       const Next1 = map.createLayer('Next', tileset)

update(t: number, dt: number){       
        
    this.physics.world.collide(this.faune, Next1, ()=>{
        console.log("testing")
        this.scene.stop(),
        this.scene.start('secondmap');
        });
```

The problem with this however is that I can not access next1 to collide with my player character "faune" since the error given is that I "Cannot find name 'Next1'.". If anyone has any idea how to use this across functions with Phaser that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks, arthur

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining the function `Next1` in the `create` function and trying to access it in the `update` function.
you could, simply define a property in the `create` function, like this:

```
this.next1 = map.createLayer('Next', tileset)
```

and in the `update` function, use it like this:

```
this.physics.world.collide(this.faune, this.next1, () => { 
    // ...
});
```

> for this not to through a compiler error, when using typescript you would have to add the property to the class definition.

```
class myScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    // you can use the exact datatype if you know it
    public next1:any; 
    ...
}
```

Or simply put the `this.physics ...` code into the `create` function.

Comment: I am unable to use this.Next1 in the create variable since it does not exist on type Game and trying to move this outside the function leads to multiple more errors that are related to Phaser internally and not my code as a whole. Your point about moving it into the create function is not applicable for what im trying to achieve since it needs to update and constantly check for collision throughout.

Comment: `this.next1 = ...` creates this property in javascript. Since you are using typescript you could simply define th property in the class definition, by adding the line `public next1:any;` under the `class ... extends Phaser.Scene {` line. than the above code should compile.

Comment: @ctrl_cheeb_del is the problem solved? or do you have some more questions?